# How to calculate Quaternion with respect to a rotated coordinate system in Unity 3D?

Tags: vector, rotation, unity-game-engine, quaternions, rotational-matrices

I'm trying to rotate a vector with a Quaternion, constructed with `Quaternion.Euler(x,y,z)` it works as expected, but the problem is, rotation is done with respect to the world coordinate system, whereas I want to rotate with respect to the vector itself.

So I want to take the coordinate system as

```
z = vector's direction,     
x = vector's perpendicular (any)  
y = world y.
```

so my code is this :

```
myVector = euler * myVector;
```

however I need

```
myVector = localEuler * myVector;
```

so I need to calculate `localEuler` as a function of `euler` and `myVector`.

How can I do this ?

Thanks for any help !

### I tried :

```
localEuler = Quaternion.Euler(euler.x * myVector.x ,euler.y * myVector.y ,euler.z * myVector.z );
```

it didn't work. I guess this is the dot product.

### P.S.

I think this has a built-in code for `Transform`s : `Transform.RotateAround()`, but I need to do it with a `Vector3`, not a `Transform`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my issue.

My solution was this :

- Use `Quaternion.AxisAngle(angle : float , rotationAxis : Vector3)`;

so for example, to rotate around "local" x, the `rotationAxis` should be myVector's perpendicular, which is computed like this :

```
var rotationAxis : Vector3 = Quaternion.Euler(0,90,0) * myVector;
rotationAxis.y = 0;
```

then the new quaternion is computed like this :

```
var localEuler:Quaternion = Quaternion.AngleAxis(euler.x , rotationAxis);
```

then the vector is rotated correctly :

```
myVector = localEuler * myVector;
```

Comment: Hi, I don't understand your answer.  rotationAxis is perpendicular to myVector in what direction.  It's 3D space after all.

Comment: @Boon yes the sentence does not fully-define the perpendicular, however the equation below it explains what it means. You can experiment with it and see which perpendicular you get.